# Customization of Placeholder

Tags: html, css, hover, textarea, placeholder

Well, I'm tryin' to change the colour of a placeholder when hovering...

**CSS**

```
#principal form label textarea::-webkit-textarea-placeholder:hover {
    color:#2278CE;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea cols="93" rows="15" maxlength="1000" placeholder="Write here."></textarea>
```

I need to know if it's right, if it isn't, how to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only change is the position of the :hover. You have to use the :hover pseudo element prior to ::-webkit-input-placeholder. Try this:

```
textarea:hover::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
  color:#2278CE;
}
```